# Postfix/Dovecot Issues receiving Mail

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I am having an issue with PostFix and Dovecot. I followed this guide: https://github.com/opensolutions/ViMbAdmin/wiki/Mail-System-Install-on-Ubuntu   and when mail is sent into the server, this is in the mail.log

```
Oct 26 12:40:11 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[13551]: connect from nm3-vm2.bt.bullet.mail.ir2.yahoo.com[212.82.99.122]
Oct 26 12:40:11 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[13551]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/dovecot-auth failed: No such file or directory
Oct 26 12:40:11 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[13551]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Oct 26 12:40:12 vps31465 postfix/master[13383]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 13551 exit status 1
Oct 26 12:40:12 vps31465 postfix/master[13383]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

This is my output from postfix -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = polynet.me, vps31465.vps.ovh.ca, localhost.vps.ovh.ca, localhost
myhostname = vps31465.vps.ovh.ca
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

And my Output from doveconf -n

```
root@vps31465:~# doveconf -n
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab093.5 x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve pop3"
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

The domain is mail.polynet.me.

I don't know where I have gone wrong.

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `postfix -n` is not a working command.  I think you meant `postconf`?

Answer (score 5):

OK, so firstly it looks like your incoming mail transaction is running into problems with SASL authentication.

```
Oct 26 12:40:11 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[13551]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/dovecot-auth failed: No such file or directory
```

That path looks to have come from here, in what I assume is `postconf` output (contrary to how you describe how you got it):

```
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
```

That's a path to a socket, which is relative to $queue_directory.  I'm not sure why that's not in your (assumed) postconf output.  On my system it's /var/spool/postfix.

So check that that path exists (presumably it doesn't)

Your `doveconf -n` output actually looks like a repeat of your postconf output, so I can only do so much.  On my system I have a stanza like so:

```
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
```

Which creates the socket which postfix talks to to deliver email.  You've named your socket file `dovecot-auth` instead of `auth`, which seems sensible enough.  I'm guessing though that you have something wrong in configuring that socket for postfix to talk to.

Please fix the configuration listings in your question, or I might have to down-vote it.

EDIT: I took a look at the link you've been using.  It refers to a gist with instructions for dovecot setup, which I think you've missed entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the original post now, and await further assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Now i ave progressed a litle bit further, I have the following issues.

```
    Oct 26 18:07:54 vps31465 postfix/lmtp[14820]: 751721E2624: to=<test@polynet.me>, relay=none, delay=0.44, delays=0.43/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to vps31465.vps.ovh.ca[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
Oct 26 18:07:54 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[14812]: F38391E2628: client=nm5-vm2.bt.bullet.mail.ir2.yahoo.com[212.82.99.124]
Oct 26 18:07:55 vps31465 postfix/cleanup[14817]: F38391E2628: message-id=<1414360873.47140.YahooMailNeo@web87701.mail.ir2.yahoo.com>
Oct 26 18:07:55 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[14818]: disconnect from nm5-vm2.bt.bullet.mail.ir2.yahoo.com[212.82.99.124]
Oct 26 18:07:55 vps31465 postfix/qmgr[14797]: F38391E2628: from=<malloyj@btinternet.com>, size=18027, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 26 18:07:55 vps31465 postfix/lmtp[14820]: F38391E2628: to=<test@polynet.me>, relay=none, delay=0.41, delays=0.41/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to vps31465.vps.ovh.ca[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
Oct 26 18:07:55 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[14812]: disconnect from nm5-vm2.bt.bullet.mail.ir2.yahoo.com[212.82.99.124]
Oct 26 18:08:15 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[14818]: connect from localhost[::1]
Oct 26 18:08:15 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[14818]: BA6271E262C: client=localhost[::1]
Oct 26 18:08:15 vps31465 postfix/cleanup[14817]: BA6271E262C: message-id=<20141026220815.BA6271E262C@vps31465.vps.ovh.ca>
Oct 26 18:08:15 vps31465 postfix/qmgr[14797]: BA6271E262C: from=<support@example.com>, size=2513, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 26 18:08:15 vps31465 postfix/smtpd[14818]: disconnect from localhost[::1]
Oct 26 18:08:15 vps31465 postfix/lmtp[14820]: BA6271E262C: to=<test@polynet.me>, relay=none, delay=0.54, delays=0.54/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to vps31465.vps.ovh.ca[private/dovecot-lmtp]: No such file or directory)
```

I am unsure how to move forward from this. These are my current Postfix config:

```
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = vps31465.vps.ovh.ca
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =  vps31465.vps.ovh.ca, localhost.vps.ovh.ca, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_mailbox_base = /srv/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 2000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
#dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

And my dovecot:

```
 root@vps31465:/etc/dovecot# dovecot -n
# 2.2.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab093.5 x86_64 Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/sieve
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Any Ideas what I am missing now??

Comment: You're not really on the same question any more.  Different problem this time, different symptom, etc.  No sign that you've gotten authentication working - you're probably just running an open relay.  Maybe you should employ someone for a few hours to help you get started?